# How to Connect live database in c++ by using codeblocks

Tags: c++, database, libmysql

```
#include <iostream>
#include<mysql.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MYSQL* conn;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn,"sql12.freemysqlhosting.net","sql123893..","nYES4ifTZ1","sql123893..", 0, NULL, 0);
    if(conn){
        cout<<"Connected";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Not Connected";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to connect live database in my cpp application
But it not connecting
please anyone give example to connect live database in cpp in codeblocks

Comment: Maybe your account information is incorrect. Does it connect in MySQL workbench with the same account info?

Comment: Please tell us what you saw, not just your interpretation. Also, read the functions' documentation to find out about how they signal errors and how to distinguish different error types.

Comment: @drescherjm yes its connected i have checked in http://www.phpmyadmin.co/ this site